# Multiple Backgrounds on Body

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is possible but can i put one transparent image over the standard background image on the website.

```
    body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: #133e6f url({{ site_img_dir }}/body-bg.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

This is the normal background image. I want to add another transparent .png over this one which is a non-repeat image. How can this be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**To have Multiple Backgrounds on a Single Element:**

```
.myclass {
  background: background1, background2, ..., backgroundN;
}
```

**More complex example:** 

3 backgrounds with other background properties:

**Note1:** You can define `background-repeat` and `background-position` (and others like `background-size`) properties for each of the 3 backgrounds individually.

```
.multi_bg_example {
  /* Background 1, an image   */ background: url(img1),
  /* Background 2, a gradient */ linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),  rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)),
  /* Background 3, an image   */ url(img3);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: bottom right, left, right;
}
```

**Note2:** The first one appears on top, second one below it, etc...

**Source:** Mozilla Developer Network, CSS multiple backgrounds:

http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: This doesn't work either, the second image looks like it's alwys hidden under the original background. And this way I cant use links and absolute positions on the transparent image.

Comment: They appear in order, change the order in a way that suits your needs. The first one appears on top, second one below it etc...

Comment: With this configuration, how do I add the background color that was in before, to fill up the rest of the background? Also how do I make the new transparent image clickable and se her position absolute, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just add another url after a coma and it should work.

```
background: url('/images/body-bg.gif'), url('/images/anotherImage.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

You can find more info [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).

**UPDATE**

You can find working example [here, on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNsB2/). Sorry for the images, random gif and png from google.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Only the first image shows and now the #133e6f is missing as well which is needed too.

Comment: Works for me on latest Chromium. Are you sure that the png has got opacity set? Also, what browser are you using?