# Compass Linear Gradient + Image

Tags: css, compass-sass

Is it possible to add a linear gradient and an image to the same element with Compass? Here is the code I am trying but I can't seem to get it to display:

```
background-color: #ffffff; // Old browsers
@include filter-gradient(#ffffff, #ededed, vertical); // IE6-8
$experimental-support-for-svg: true;
@include background(linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%), image-url('../img/questionmark.png' top, left, no-repeat));
padding: 10px;
font-size: 14px;
border-bottom:  solid 1px #d3d3d3;
```

Comment: Not specific to Compass, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450039/multiple-backgrounds-on-body/16450098#16450098

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible <s>- instead of non-existing `image-url` use `url`</s>. In your example gradient will cover the image (what comes first in the declaration in closer to top).

The example [pen](http://codepen.io/thelitek/pen/LAaKC) with gradient and image.

### Edit

The answer, while solving the problem, was misleading.

### The `image-url` function

Contrary to what I wrote before it [does](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url) exist. It returns url to the image relative to compass images folder.