# Simple Non Scrolling Background Image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have what is probably a simple question but I can't find the answer for it. I have a background image that looks fine and tiles fine and scrolls fine. However, I have a second background image that is layered on top of it that is put inside a wrapper div ("whiteBackground" I believe it's called) and I do not want that one to scroll with the page. As the content and text gets longer and forces the user to scroll I'd like for the second background to stay static. That way while the user scrolls down the page it would just make it seem AS IF the second background was just perfectly still.

I've tried to do a fixed background attachment in my "wrapper" div but it's a no go.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/SMc9R/

```
`#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width:960px;
    min-height:768px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background-image:url('images/white_background.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family:'MuroRegular';
}`
```

This is the main part I believe the problem is at.

There are no images but I figured that my markup and CSS should be enough. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you want to have two backgrounds, it is possible to have multiple backgrounds on a single element: [Multiple Backgrounds on a Single Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450039/multiple-backgrounds-on-body/16450098#16450098)

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** :http://jsfiddle.net/SMc9R/1/ DO YOU want like this.. or specify any correction regarding this correction...

```
 #banner {
position: absolute;
float:left;
width: 960px;
height:60px;
text-align: center;
font-family:'AmaticBold';
font-size: 50px;
background-image:url('images/banner.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index: 4;
 }
```